# GA - Acquisition menu is missing "All Traffic"?

Tags: google-analytics, referrals

I've setup GA on my personal website, and I am getting information flowing to my dashboard, and no apparent errors, but I can't seem to find any full referral URLs.  All tutorials and pictures that I see tell you to go "Acquisition > All Traffic > Referrals", but my Acquisition menu doesn't even have an "All Traffic" menu.  It just has "Overview" "User Acquisition" "Traffic Acquisition".  "Traffic acquisition" seems to have referrals, but only root level site referrals and I can't see exactly where the traffic is coming from.

Is there something in the config that I'm missing? My google-fu has failed me on this, as every tutorial tells me that "All Traffic" is where to go.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of 2023, it just has to be enabled manually.
Go to Reporting > Library (Left bottom corner) > in the Collections click on 3 dots and click publish

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this is a difference between GA4 and Google UA experience.  I had to enable a UA property and link it to my newly created GA4 property to get all of the data to come through.

Comment: Could you explain what you did ? 
I have the same issue and some of my sites do not show "all traffic" and other menu points.
It seems like that happens when using the new "domain property" instead of the old site-property in google search console but that's nothing I can change now.